# Intermittent Access Denied errors for anonymous users

Tags: 8, users, caching

I'm running into seemingly random Access Denied errors that occasionally come up on most (but not always all) node pages for anonymous and low-level users (anyone without the "Bypass content access control" permission).

- I've rebuilt permissions a few times, which fixes it for awhile too, but the behavior returns.
- I've scoured user permissions and don't think there's anything incorrect in there.
- We are not using any contrib node access modules.

Clearing the site caches fixes this, but it comes back after awhile, so I suspect this is cache-related. We use Redis.

This is a pretty new Drupal 8 site that used the Lightning install profile. We use Panels/Panelizer for layouts. We have a bit of custom code in place (a few form alters, a few blocks, a few redirects, nothing particularly complex - but it's certainly possible there's something off in there).

Anyone seen this before or have troubleshooting suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out, not particularly efficiently (never really found a good way to backtrace this), but got there nonetheless.

The issue was coming from the [Custom Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_perms) module, which I'd incorrectly written off as innocent early on in troubleshooting since I use it on other sites without issue. Whoops.

That module lets you create permissions via a UI for any path you'd like. We had one in place that created a permission that was already defined by core (managing blocks -- accessing admin/structure/block). Removing this redundant permission fixed our problem here. (Uninstalling the module also fixed the issue.)

I'll post an issue in that module's queue if it's reproducible with a clean install.